# How to change pitch beyond 1 or -1 in C# + XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, pitch

I need to be able to have more freedom than just 2 octaves to create the thing I want to, but I can't with XNA. I do realize there probably isn't a way to get the program to accept a larger/smaller value, but is there a way around it? like taking the sound at the lowest pitch, and creating a new one as that so I can lower it more?

Comment: afaik pitch will not change just pitch but also speed. if you don't like that you may have to change the sound data yourself.

Comment: Or use another library such as BASS.NET or FMOD.

Comment: Looks like in MonoGame, only XACT allows pitch beyond -1 and 1 (even -1 and 1 themselves cause ArgumentOutOfRangeException, although I'm not sure if this part is a bug or not). See https://gamefromscratch.com/monogame-tutorial-audio/ > "Use XACT"

Comment: Sorry, the section name is actually "Using XACT" and I've added a bug for -1 and 1 not being supported https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/7659 although for values beyond, without XACT, you'd need to assume using OpenAL and hack the range check yourself. Sorry to hijack this question with MonoGame, but I'll assume MonoGame developers look for old XNA questions frequently anyway.