# Pitch shifting beyond 1 octave in MonoGame

Tags: c#, audio, xna, monogame

I would like to play some sounds in MonoGame but pitch-shifted by several octaves. The API documentionation states that the pitch may only be shifted by 1 octave up or down.

How do I play a sound with a pitch shift beyond these limits?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115326/how-to-change-pitch-beyond-1-or-1-in-c-sharp-xna) is related but applies to XNA.